# Storing Email addresss in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column called `Email Address` that I want to mask the display of the addresses with `*`.

Something like this:

```
aaron0@adventure-works.com --> a****0@adventure-works.com
aaron1@adventure-works.com --> a****1@adventure-works.com
aaron14@adventure-works.com --> a*****4@adventure-works.com
```

How can I achieve this? How to implement the stuff or replace function?

Comment: Do you want to actually **store** the e-mail addresses masked like that - or only display them with `*` masking the data?

Comment: Do you want one- and two-character [local-parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part) exposed, i.e. `eh@foo.ca` and `a@foo.gov`? How do you want quoted strings handled, e.g. `"just me"@foo.edu` becomes `"*******"@foo.edu`? What about `" "@example.org`?

Comment: If you have a need to hide them in the database, I'd use column level encryption. If this is just a presentation preference, I'd leave that the application or front end.

Answer (score 2):

Hiding data in SQL Server can be obtained by using data masks.
For instance when using:

```
ALTER COLUMN EmailAddress NVARCHAR(100) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'email()')
```

then *aaron0@adventure-works.com* will be displayed as *aXXX@XXX.com*.

Note it will always result in ending with .com, no matter what the actual top level domain of the email address is.

You can also use partial masking:

```
ALTER COLUMN EmailAddress NVARCHAR(100) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(3, "XXXXX", 9)')
```

then *aaron0@adventure-works.com* will be displayed as *aarXXXXXworks.com*.

Both `email()` and `partial()` won't result exactly in what you try to obtain though, which doesn't seem to be possible, because the position of the @ depends on the email address.

These articles describe data masking pretty well:

- https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-data-masking-in-sql-server-2/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1):

If you are just concerned with masking the email addresses when selecting them from the table, you can do that numerous ways using SQL Server's existing string functions.

One way would be to use a combination of *stuff* and *charindex*

```
with t as ( -- Sample data
  select * from (values
    ('aaron0@adventure-works.com'),
    ('aaron1@adventure-works.com'),
    ('aaron14@adventure-works.com')
  )e(email)
)  
select email, Stuff(email, 2, p, Replicate('*', p)) masked
from t
cross apply(values(CharIndex('@', email) - 3))a(p);
```